# How to grant a permission to edit terms for a specific user?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, users

I have taxonomy terms with a user reference field. I want users to be able to edit taxonomy terms they related with.

I'm looking for something similar to [`hook_node_access`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_access/7) or [`hook_node_grants`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_grants/7) with [`hook_node_access_records`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_access_records/7) for nodes.

Is there a code/module to grant taxonomy permissions to specific users?

Comment: Checkout https://www.drupal.org/project/term_permissions.

Comment: May be https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_access is something for you?

Comment: Robin, Sumit Madan - No, you cannot apply permission to specific users. Only to role